# Google Sheets: How can I sort a range of data but ignore 1 specific row?

Tags: sorting, google-sheets

I have a range of data that needs to be sorted (example: B3:D1000) but I want to ignore 1 specific row (example: row B370). Is there a way to write a SORTN function to sort the data while ignoring that one specific row?

Trying to avoid writing a separate FILTER function if possible.

Comment: By 'ignore', do you mean 'not include in the sort output' or 'maintain the position of this row in the array and sort everything else'?

Answer (score 0):

To leave out row 370 and show the rest of the data sorted by column `B`, use this:

```
=sort( filter(B3:D, row(B3:D) <> 370) )
```